# How do I do an Anti Match Pattern on Keyword Field Elasticsearch Query 6.4.2

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

The problem:

Our log data has 27-34 million entries for a /event-heartbeat.
I need to filter those entries out to see just viable log messages in Kibana.

Using Kibana filters with wildcards does not work. Thus, I think I will have to write QueryDSL to do it in version 6.4.2 Elasticsearch to get it to filter out the event heart beats.

I have been looking and I can't find any good explanations on how to do an anti-pattern match so to search for all entries that don't have /event-heartbeat in the message.

Here is the log message:

```
@timestamp:
    June 14th 2019, 12:39:09.225
host.name:
    iislogs-production
source:
    C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC5\u_ex19061412.log
offset:
    83,944,181
message:
    2019-06-14 19:39:06 0.0.0.0 GET /event-heartbeat id=Budrug2UDw 443 - 0.0.0.0 - - 200 0 0 31
prospector.type:
    log
input.type:
    log
beat.name:
    iislogs-production
beat.hostname:
    MYHOSTNAME
beat.version:
    6.4.2
_id:
    yg6AV2sB0_n
_type:
    doc
_index:
    iislogs-production-6.4.2-2019.06.14
_score:
    -
```

Message is a keyword field so I can do painless scripting on it.

I've used Lucene syntax

```
NOT message: "*/event-heartbeat*"

This is the anti pattern the kibana filter generates.
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "message": "*event-heartbeat*"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried the proposed solution below by huglap. I also adjusted my query based on his comment and tried two ways. I adjust it with the term word instead of match and tried both ways because the field technically is a keyword so I could do painless scripting on it. The query still returns event heartbeat log entries.

[image]

[image]

Here are the two queries I tried from the below proposed solution:

```
GET /iislogs-production-*/_search
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":{
            "match_all":{

            }
         },
         "filter":{
            "bool":{
               "must_not":[
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "message.whitespace":"event-heartbeat"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

GET /iislogs-production-*/_search
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":{
            "match_all":{

            }
         },
         "filter":{
            "bool":{
               "must_not":[
                  {
                     "match":{
                        "message.whitespace":"event-heartbeat"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Index Mapping:
https://gist.github.com/zukeru/907a9b2fa2f0d6f91a532b0865131988

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about a 'must_not' bool query?
Since your going for the whole set and not really caring about shaping the relevancy function, I suggest the use of a filter instead of a query. You'll get better performance.

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":{
            "match_all":{

            }
         },
         "filter":{
            "bool":{
               "must_not":[
                  {
                     "match":{
                        "message.whitespace":"event-heartbeat"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This example assumes you are querying against a text field, thus the use of a 'match' query instead of a 'term' one.
You also need to make sure that the field is analyzed (really tokenized) according to your goals. The fact that you have a dash in your query term will create problems if you're using a simple or even a standard analyser. Elasticsearch would break the term in two words. You could try the whitespace analyser on that one or just remove the dash from the query.

Comment: I've tried it both with MATCH and TERM because technically it is a keyword field so I can do scripted plainless on it to extract IP's which works but still both return values with /event-heartbeat in them. I will describe it for you and update the questions. @huglap